# Is there an obvious entry point to Orchard CMS view rendering functionality that would allow me to use Orchard to render views conditionally?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, orchardcms

I like Orchard CMS but I don't like it enough to rebuild my entire web app on top of it.

Instead I would like to be able to delegate responsibility for view rendering and route handling to Orchard for specific routes, and handle the rest myself.

For instance, when a request comes in, if it has the prefix `/Orchard` then I would delegate the request to Orchard entirely, using it like a black box (unaware of implementation details). Otherwise, I would handle it myself. On the other hand, when Orchard forms links, it would do so relative to `/Orchard`.

Is there an obvious way to achieve this without seriously hacking Orchard?

Comment: Some have done it from what I heard, but it's not going to be easy. What should be relatively easy is to keep Orchard in a separate IIS application.